# How to get collision detection among many objects to many players

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

I have 3-4 players in game and many objects (like stone, tree, cactus..etc). I have to find the collision detection between the objects and the players.

What is the easiest way with the speed performance to find the collision between objects and players.

If I pass player position for step movement to object class to find the collision detection it might be slow performance (each_step_of_player * all_objects).

Another idea I had is that I will write a schedule function for each object in Object class and for each schedule function call I will check collision with all player position ( Object * all_players). How is this idea regarding the speed performance?

Any another idea will be appreciate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use grid-based collision detection.

Break your screen into grid of square cells, each cell at least as large as the largest object (this is important). Each object is assigned a cell, based on where the center of the object is. When you move the object, you reassign it to corresponding cell. Now you don't have to check an object against *all* other objects for collision, only against objects in its cell and adjacent cells.

Comment: Reference as in "where to get more info"? I read about grid-based detection in "AdvancED ActionScript 3.0 Animation" by Keith Peters.